# PHP Login Script - Echo Issues

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm trying to put a login script together... but I'm having issues with the first bit.. I've included a database connection file.. now I'm trying to make sure the user does not leave the fields blank.. here is the code:

```
<?php 

// create database connection 

$db = include 'dbcon.php';

// executes code if and when form has been submitted 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo 'Error!' ; }

}

?>
```

The problem I'm having is that it won't print out the echo messages.. why is it doing this?

Comment: can you paste the HTML form tag elements?

Comment: Paste code of `dbcon.php` file

Comment: Make sure you specify `method="post"` in the form, otherwise it will default to `GET`.

Comment: besides other comments ^ your query may also be failing. This question is next to impossible to solve in its current state.

Comment: and this `$db = include 'dbcon.php';` *Hmm....*, that's questionable.

Comment: put some more code..and why are you assigning include to variable..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working for me: Make sure you have used the correct name for input fields.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    echo 'Error!' ;}  } 



<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Username <input class="input-box" type="text" name="username"></p>
    <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
    <p class="submit"><input class="input-box" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Nope... I placed that code in a separate php file and it still displays a blank screen when I submit the form!

Comment: @SohailArif - If it worked, then it should display a blank screen. It will only echo the *Error!* when the username or password fields are left blank.

Comment: it should display "error" when there's nothing in the fields and the form is submitted.... if there is something in the field and its submitted.. then it should be blank... you are right.

Answer (score 0):

@Sohail,

You can try using the 'required' keyword inside the input tags.

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
<input type="password" name="pwd" required>
```

This would make sure the form will not be submitted unless User enters some value for the fields.

You can read more about the required attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Also, be aware that form can still be submitted if blank spaces are provided in the input fields.

Alternatively, you can do form validation before the form is submitted. 
Try this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp). This should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error.. the problem was in the html code ... I changed it from this:

```
<input type="submit" value="login">
```

to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
```

Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Comment: your question would have been solved within seconds probably, had you shown us your related form code. Your question was closed accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow.. I tried pasting my html code in but it was giving me a code format error.